# What was Neitzche calling "old frigid and tedious frogs"?

Tags: nietzsche, psychology, genealogy-of-morals

After the first paragraph of the first essay of *On the Genealogy of Morals*, Nietzsche discusses how English psychologists may be motivated to study the darker side of "our inner world". Then he stated the following:

> But I am told that it is simply a case of old frigid and tedious frogs crawling and hopping around men and inside men, as if they were as thoroughly at home there, as they would be in a swamp.

What does this analogy entail? Is Nietzsche saying that people have likened undesirable traits to frogs, with men being the swamp?

Comment: Nietzsche said another thing about frogs & swamps, discussed here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/60224/what-does-this-zarathustras-sentence-mean/79531#79531

Comment: IMO there is nothing deep there... only a deep contempt for [English psychologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_psychology#Early_British)

Comment: But maybe also [British moral philosophers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/utilitarianism-history/#ClaApp) are involved in the rant.